# React input is being cleared after js is loaded

Tags: reactjs, redux, isomorphic-javascript

Taken from the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), I have a similar component that looks like the following:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  }
}
```

Can't be simpler, and it works like the example says it should.

The thing is that I have an isomorphic application (done with `redux-connect`).

From the server, it will load an input (it will there run the first "render") and after that goes to a client, and after js loads, it will run a second "render".
The problem is that if the user types something on that "input" before js loads, it will be cleared after js is loaded since the second "render" will re-render the input and will clear the input removing the text written by the user.

Is there anything I can do to prevent that issue?

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227517/how-to-handle-early-input-to-isomorphically-rendered-forms